# Arduino recorder with SD card module

Tags: esp8266, programming

Can any one suggest me best device in cheap rates to record audio in to SD-card and vice versa from the speaker......i want to record audio into the sd card like as feedback from customer

Comment: You can buy a mini digital voice recorder on eBay for $5. Why would you waste your time bodging something that won't work well with an Arduino?

Comment: But i want to integrate it with my project work any external device will not work for it as i have to use only boards.

Comment: You should remove the tags `bluetooth` and `arduino-uno` from your question

Comment: Sure Removing!!

Comment: @Majenko just for my curiosity, why wouldn't this be possible with an Arduino? 44.1 KHz/16 bit/stereo doesn't seem unrealistic for a 16 MHz Arduino MCU.

Answer (score 0):

For decent audio recordings, you need an external (16 or 24 bit, 44.1 KHz or more) ADC with at least two channels (stereo).

To save it to an SD, you can buy a so called SD data logger, they are very cheap. Not all SD cards are compatible so you might have to try several ones. The protocol used is SPI.

Comment: OK Michel i will try this!! Thanks for your support :)

Comment: You're welcome, good luck with your project (if it helped you, please consider upvoting/accepting an answer).